# Requests in form: http://www.site.com/one/two/three/ in Apache 2

Tags: apache

how can I configure Apache server, to mantain requests such as:
    http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/
(i mean the /one/two/three)?

What's the name of this technique and how it is done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can do that with Apache Forcetype](http://www.websitepublisher.net/article/search_engine_friendly_urls/2).

> Typically a web server knows how to
>   handle requests by the extension any
>   given file has. For instance, if a
>   file has a .php extension Apache knows
>   to parse it for PHP code before
>   sending it to the browser. Apache's
>   ForceType directive allows you to
>   override any default mime types you
>   have set up. Usually it may be used to
>   parse an .html page as php or
>   something similar, but in this case we
>   will be using it to parse a file with
>   no extension as php.
>
> So instead of using article.php, as we
>   did in method 1, rename that file to
>   just "article" with no extension. You
>   will be able to access it like this:
>   `http://www.domain.com/article/999/12/`.
>   Utilizing Apache's look back feature
>   and $PATH_INFO variable as described
>   in method 1. But as of right now
>   Apache doesn't yet know to that
>   "article" needs to be parsed as php.
>   To achieve that you must add the
>   following to your .htaccess file.
>
> ```
> <Files article> ForceType
>     application/x-httpd-php  
> </Files>
> ```
>
> This
>   is known as a container. Instead of
>   applying directives to all files
>   Apache allows you to limit them by
>   filename, location, or directory. You
>   need create a container as above and
>   place the directives inside it. In
>   this case we are using a file
>   container, we identify "article" as
>   the file we are concerned with and
>   then we list the directives we want
>   applied to this file before closing
>   off the container.
>
> With the directive inside the
>   container we are telling Apache to
>   parse "article" as a php script even
>   though it has no file extension. This
>   allows us to get rid of the period in
>   the URL that causes the problems yet
>   still use the PATH_INFO method to
>   manage our site.

Comment: how it is done for example on Facebook where there is a lot of such pages? Majority of users have their own site: `http://www.facebook.com/username`. I don't think that they create for every user `<Files username> ForceType
    application/x-httpd-php  
</Files> `

Comment: They could be using mod_rewrite. There is definitely more then one way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Most sites with this structure would use mod_rewrite to rewrite all requests to a single file, which would bootstrap a framework or CMS. The CMS or framework would then read and parse the URI and handle internally as designed.